# number of integer solution of quadratic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Number of integral solution of

> $(k+1)x^2-2kx+(k+1)=0$

What I Try ::

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the integer  roots of given equation.

Then we have $\displaystyle \alpha+\beta=\frac{2k}{k+1}$ and $\displaystyle \alpha\beta=\frac{k+1}{k+1}=1$

So we have $\displaystyle \alpha\beta=1\Longrightarrow (\alpha,\beta)=(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$

$\bullet (\alpha,\beta)=(1,1),$ Then $\displaystyle 2=\frac{2k}{k+1}\Longrightarrow 1=0$

It is false.

$\bullet (\alpha,\beta)=(-1,-1)$, Then $\displaystyle -2=\frac{2k}{k+1}\Longrightarrow k=-\frac{1}{2}$

So no integer value of $k$ exists.

Is I am doing right, If not then how can I find number of integer solution.

Comment: Do you need both roots to be integer? You could have an integer and its reciprocal as roots like $x=2, k=-5$ for instance...

Comment: You also missed case $k=-1$, dividing by $k+1$ implicitly assumes $k\neq -1$

Comment: Do you need $k$ to be integer, or just the roots of the equation?

Comment: @Andrei just the root of the equation is integer.